# Changes between DHCP and Static IP. Randomly?

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I have a Debian Lenny server, that was setup with DHCP at install time, but I have changed it to have a static IP instead.

Now it changes between having a dhcp and a static ip almost randomly.

Is this `/etc/network/interfaces` correct?

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static
       address 192.168.0.24
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       network 192.168.0.0
       broadcast 192.168.0.255
       gateway 192.168.0.1

dns-nameservers 192.168.0.9
dns-search example.com
```

Or are there other config files I have to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a DHCP client running? If it is and picks up a lease, it will override the static IP; I often find that I have to manually kill it (the DHCP client) once I've set the interfaces static and restarted networking.

Comment: There sure was =) How do I disable it, so it doesn't start at boot up? `chkconfig --list` doesn't list anything dhcp related.

Comment: Killing it did the trick. It didn't restart after reboot. Great!

Answer (score 1):

Are you running a GUI? If you are, you want to check to see if you have got **networkmanager** running anywhere. If it is, you can choose to use that instead of editing your `/etc/networking/interfaces` directly.

Comment: Interesting idea. Just checked. No GUI and no NetworkManager though.